Visual Studio unable to open Tabular model after upgrade to VS Enterprise
In the past I developed and deployed a Tabular model to Analysis Services using Visual Studio v 14 Community edition. Recently I upgraded to Visual Studio V17 Enterprise and tried to load the same solution file but I am presented with the following error:

I already installed the only required extension which is Microsoft Analysis Services projects.
Opening the report mentioned in the error I get this message:
BI_DataModel.smproj: The application which this project type is based on was not found. Please try this link for further information: 6870e480-7721-4708-bfb8-9ae898aa21b3

Do you have any ideas?

Did you also install SSDT?

@Dai do you mean SSDT Lifecycle Extension?

No, I mean SSDT itself: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-ver16

@Dai I checked, I should have SSDT because it comes with VS... is there a more precise way to check it?

VS comes with SSDT, yes - that just means the SSDT components can be selected in the installer; but SSDT is not always installed with VS: you need to specifically select it during installation - just like the C++ editor and compiler, or the VS Extension SDK.

@Dai thanks for the clarification. VS was installed by my IT, is there a way to check if SSDT was selected or not?

Go Help > About, you should see "SQL Server Data Tools - 17.10.178.1" (or similar) in the list.

I confirm it is installed but still getting the incompatible error...

The only solution for me has been to request to my IT Department to uninstall and reinstall of Visual Studio.

Make sure SQL Server Data Tools* and the SQL Analysis Services extension are installed. Here's the install doc we use (you can ignore the Oracle step):

